# Creating a link from my DB saved text with PHP

Tags: php, html, dynamic

I am a bit stumped. I want to

1. Get the "directory/filename with a space.pdf" from the DB (done)
2. Create a page that displays the list of available pdf's (Here the fault lies)

   ```
   $stringOptions= $stringOptions. "<li><a href=". rawurldecode ($row['docContent']) .">". $row['docData'] ."</a></li>";
   ```
3. Display the php page in the html. (Done)

The links get generated as `www.thedomain.com/documents/filename` and the rest `with a space.pdf` is lost. Or it creates a link `/documents/filename+with+a+space` and the `.pdf` is cut off and the domain is lost.

I tried encodeurl and rawencodeurl with the correlating rawdecodeurl and decodeurl functions but the URL is never successfully created. I have read the PHP manual but I am not a good enough coder to see what other functions I could/should use. Any help or direction please.

Comment: try this `$stringOptions= $stringOptions. "<li><a href=\"". urlencode($row['docContent']) ."\">". $row['docData'] ."</a></li>";
`

Comment: Need to check URL and see if the domain is in it, otherwise you want `./documents/filename` so that it works with a relative path.

Comment: Thanks Gaurav Singh. This completely solved my issue. This was very difficult for me but I see what you did and I understand! THANKS!